# .ashx image handler not working on production server

Tags: asp.net, iis, handler, ashx

I developed a little .ashx handler that returns an image so I could do

```
<img src="myhandler.ashx?query=string">
```

It worked perfectly on my dev machine.  I moved it to the production server (IIS on Server 2008) and it broke.  By "broke", I mean it no longer returns a valid image.  The handler calls an external application to generate the image - I had the path wrong, fixed it, and all that accomplished was to make the warnings stop showing up in the event log.

I know it has permission to run the program. I manually ran the command I'm passing it and successfully generated an image.  There are no errors in the event log and the IIS log says it responds with a 200/OK.  I'm a little lost as to how I should go about debugging this further.

Comment: What does firebug say? If u haven't used it... I would suggest it

Comment: Clearly, firebug only sees the image tag as above.  I can see the request happen to the handler, which shows a 0B transfer, so no data's getting sent to the browser.  Which means somethings broken somewhere server-side, I think.  But if that were the case, I would expect to see an error in the event log...

Comment: Meat of the handler: http://pastebin.com/ZKSWVLkU

Comment: What do you get when you call this the handler directly? http://mysite/myhandler.ashx?query=string

Comment: Just a blank page - chrome dev tools shows a 0B transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, got it solved.

The discrepancies between my dev environment and the production server led to the need to double-escape a special character that .NET is fine with but my external program interprets specially.  The entire problem was unrelated to the handler.

Thanks for the help, though.